# How strict is ODR rule for C++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates, one-definition-rule

Suppose I have a complex project P that uses libraries A and B, and these libraries use header-only library T containing some templates.

```
P --> A --> T(1.0)
|
 ---> B --> T(1.0)
```

The authors of T release version 1.1, which is backward compatible at the source level, i.e. any user of T can be recompiled with the new version, and the program will continue to work. Suppose A decides to upgrade, but B stays on T version 1.0.

```
P --> A --> T(1.1)
|
 ---> B --> T(1.0)
```

Am I correct in assuming that virtually *any* change to T would be a violation of the ODR rule, as stated here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition.

> There can be more than one definition... as long as all of the following is true:
> each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens (typically,
> appears in the same header file)

Practically speaking, are there any technically illegal, but practically "safe" changes?

- If the project is statically linked (liba.lib, libb.lib)?
- If the project is dynamically linked (a.so, b.so)?

Comment: If A and B only rely on T internally (that is, P is not aware of the dependency), then P should not be affected by A taking up version 1.1 of T, even if 1.0 and 1.1 are entirely different.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, interesting point. I don't think that's the case, at least with static linking. Suppose T has generic func<X>. A instantiates func<int> and B instantiates func<int> and func<double>. Only one instantiation of func<int> would exist throughout the project unless inlining is involved. If the linker chooses A's version, then B would use func<int> version 1.1, but func<double> version 1.0. This may lead to funny bugs, especially if T has some static state. If inlining is involved, it gets even more interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard considers any lexical change inside the definition (in terms of tokens after preprocessing) to violate the one definition rule. There are no exceptions. And this is also only the base rule. There are further requirements e.g. that all corresponding names in the definitions will refer to the same entity in each definition (after overload resolution and partial template specialization matching).

So, from that point of view, you always have to recompile every translation unit in your program (whether in a library or not) that includes the header with the modified definition.

Of course that's usually not how it is done in practice.

In practice one can generally rely on the ABI specification, or at least common patterns in ABI specifications, as well as general knowledge how compilers work or how linking on the specific platforms of interest works. With that knowledge it is often possible to derive that certain changes will not have any unintended consequences even if the header file is mixed with an old version between translation units.

Unfortunately there is no easy rule to follow. It will depend on what *exactly* you intent to change.

For a simple example: Adding a non-virtual non-special function with a new name as a class member will generally be fine. The way compilers and ABIs work, nothing at the ABI level will change by doing this and because the name is new there is no risk of overload resolution resulting in indirect ODR violations if e.g. one inline function definition happens to use the old overload resolution result and another definition for the same function happens to use the new one.

---

One way to avoid at least the direct ODR issues completely is to wrap the whole header-only library in an unnamed namespace, causing everything in it (including classes and templates) to have internal linkage, i.e. they will simply be different entities in every translation unit.

Of course, that's usually not what one wants because it makes sharing the contents between translation units impossible.

Also, it actually increases the risk of indirect ODR violations, because any inline definition with external linkage must then not depend on the contents of the header-only library.

Comment: Thank you. Can you clarify what you mean by "the ABI specification"? Do you mean "Itanium C++ ABI" (https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/)?

Comment: @IvanKrivyakov If that's the ABI your compiler uses, then yes. But there are other ones, e.g. MSVC follows a different C++ ABI. Also, there is an underlying C ABI that differs between architectures/platforms.

Comment: I don't think MSVC publishes a complete ABI spec. At least, I could not find one. They just talk about compatibility between versions.

Comment: "Of course that's usually not how it is done in practice." What I observed in practice is that people get overconfident: they rely on a simplified or outright wrong understanding of the ABI, and then funny bugs happen. E.g. "if just add a private field, it should be fine" (usually wrong), or "it's all weak symbols, so if I only change implementations of methods, it should be fine" (sometimes right, but it depends)

Comment: @IvanKrivyakov I am also not aware of a full ABI specification for MSVC. And yes, unfortunately the only way is to either to strictly not break ODR at all or to have a good understanding of ABI, C++ overload resolution, and compiler/linker behavior. Otherwise there will be problems. Assuming that adding any data member (whether private or not) wouldn't affect ABI compatibility shows that there isn't even a basic understanding of it.